# Como solucionar este error: "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` "

Tags: regex

tengo este patron

```
"createdAt": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX",
  "name": "string",
  "type": true,
```

Debo probar los endpoints desde swagger o postman que tienen campos de fechas  con ese patron.

He tratado con esta fecha: `2019-07-04T20:20:08.135+0000`

pero obtengo este error:

```
    {
      "timestamp": "2019-07-04T20:38:38.604+0000",
      "status": 400,
      "error": "Bad Request",
      "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type 
`java.util.Date` from String \"2019-07-04T20:20:08.135+0000\": expected 
format \"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX\"; nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot 
deserialize value of type `java.util.Date` from String \"2019-07-
04T20:20:08.135+0000\": expected format \"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX\"\n
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 7, column: 16] (through 
reference chain: edu.umss.storeservice.dto.ItemDto[\"createdAt\"])",
      "path": "/items"
    }
```

Comment: @abulafia debo poner comillas, puedes darme un ejemplo porfavor

Comment: @abulafia lo que pasa que no tengo permiso de cambiar ese patron del backend, solo debo usarlo desde frontend

Comment: @abulafia swagger me pide ese formato de mi pregunta, edite mi pregunta la primera parte, y no tengo permiso de modificar ese formato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tu backend es un programa Java que intenta parsear la cadena que le envías:

```
"2019-07-04T20:38:38.604+0000"
```

usando [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (o alguna derivada) con el formato `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"`, y no encaja.

Efectivamente, el patrón `XXX` representa el offset horario (*timezone*) en el formato `+00:00`, o bien simplemente `Z`. Por tanto cadenas válidas que sí pasarían el test serían:

```
"2019-07-04T20:38:38.604+00:00"
"2019-07-04T20:38:38.604Z"
```

Pero no la que tú envías, que encajaría en cambio con el formato `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` o con `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX"` (sólo dos X en vez de tres)

**Fuente**. Mis experimentos con [este intérprete Scala interactivo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/9MkkexRrQPmUm98tz9zHLg)